# Use a group-theoretic proof to show that $\mathbb{Q}^*$ under multiplication is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^*$ under multiplication.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, infinite-groups

Use a group-theoretic proof to show that $\mathbb{Q}^*$ under multiplication is
not isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^*$ under multiplication.

**I have tried this:**

Suppose $$ \phi: \mathbb{Q}^*\to \mathbb{R}^* $$
where $\phi(x)=x^2$

Now for some $3 \in \mathbb{R}^*$
there is no mapping in $\mathbb{Q}^*$ since $\sqrt3$ does not belong to $\mathbb{Q}^*$.

Hence **$\phi$** is **not an onto function.**
Therefore $\mathbb{Q}^* \not\cong \mathbb{R}^*$.

But I am not sure if it is correct.

Also, What is a **group-theoretic proof**?

Comment: Here's a group-theoretic proof. There are only countably many elements in the group $\mathbb{Q}^\times$, and uncountably many in $\mathbb{R}^\times$. Thus there can be no isomorphism from one to the other.

Comment: What makes a proof group-theoretic? I think it's pretty hard to find a proof which doesn't reference their different cardinality or topological differences, since the reals at their core are constructed topologically.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Hi David, apologies for the inconvenience. I have updated the question.

Comment: Your proof only shows that $x\mapsto x^2$ is not an isomorphism. You need to show that **no map** is an isomorphism.

Comment: Yes.But if we take any multiplication say a.b then for a.a=3 belonging to R*, a does not belong to Q*.

Comment: I think I need to change the way its written in the form of multiplication of a and b.That will justify the proof. Thanks @halrankard

Comment: I rolled back your edits as both of the answers directly refer to your attempt. If you want to ask about a different attempt then please ask in a separate question (ideally using MathJax, which is the `$\phi(x)=x^2$` stuff in the question; you can copy-and-paste the relevant text from this question into your new question and then edit it to get what you want).

Comment: (Also, if you found either answer helpful then you should "accept" it by clicking on the tick beside it.)

Comment: Also, a "group theoretic proof" is not really a well defined notion. I guess they are meaning something like the proofs given, rather than a proof which reference their different cardinality or topological differences (as in the first two comments above).

Comment: ok.. I get it. I am new here. I'll take care of these. Thanks @user1729

Answer (score 7):

Your idea is in the right direction but $x\mapsto x^2$ is not onto. However, $x\mapsto x^3$ is onto and works. More precisely:

The map $\mathbb R^* \to \mathbb R^*$ given by $x\mapsto x^3$ is surjective and so every element of $\mathbb R^*$ is a cube.

The map $\mathbb Q^* \to \mathbb Q^*$ given by $x\mapsto x^3$ is not surjective and so not every element of $\mathbb Q^*$ is a cube of an element of $\mathbb Q^*$. For instance, $2 \in \mathbb Q^*$ is not a cube (of a rational number).

Comment: Q* is a subset of R*. So if every element of R* is a cube then so will be every element of Q*.

Comment: @VikasAditya: what lhf meant is that every real is a cube of a real, while not every rational is a cube of a rational. Every element of any group is a cube of an element of a bigger group, so it does not make sense to consider powers of "external" elements.

Comment: Ok I got the point now. Thanks @tomasz

Comment: But how is x-->x↦x3 is onto ?

Comment: For some x^3 in R* its cube root not necessarily exists in Q*. Isn't that right?

Comment: @lhf Just saw your edit. But I think this proves automorphism of Q* is not true for mapping given by x-->x^3 . Does that also prove R* is isomorphic to Q*?

Comment: @VikasAditya, no. Read it again. If the groups were isomorphic, then $2$ would be a rational cube. Prove that.

Comment: And also, please check my edit. whether the proof has some flaw?

Comment: I understand your point but the mapping you are considering is Q*-->Q* . which is not onto. This does not prove the non isomorphism for R*-->Q* by x-->x^3 @lhf

Comment: For mapping R*-->Q* it is onto. because  for 8 in Q* 2 does exist in R*

Answer (score 4):

The squaring map is not onto $\mathbf R^\times$, so it does not quite work. However, it is pretty close: the image is a subgroup of index $2$. In $\mathbf Q^\times$, the index is infinite. Thus, the two groups are not isomorphic.

(In fact, this shows that they are not even elementarily equivalent.)

Comment: A first-order sentence true in $\mathbf{R}^\times$ and false in $\mathbf{Q}^\times$ being: $(\exists x)(\forall y)(\exists z)[(x+x=0)\wedge ((z+z=y)\vee (z+z=y+x))]$. Another is $(\forall y)(\exists z)(z+z+z=y)$.